# Ontouch always call up

Tags: android

I have a problem with onTouchEvent function. 
I don't know why but when I touch the screen with my finger and then move it on the screen sometimes I 'm in the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP case whereas I continue to press the screen .
That may be because I redraw view.
thank you
Logs :

```
05-09 15:03:23.086  24856-24856/fr.myApp.motscaches V/uppp﹕ down
05-09 15:03:25.036  24856-24856/fr.myApp.motscaches V/uppp﹕ up
05-09 15:03:25.052  24856-24856/fr.myApp.motscaches V/uppp﹕ down
05-09 15:03:25.135  24856-24856/fr.myApp.motscaches V/uppp﹕ up
05-09 15:03:25.136  24856-24856/fr.myApp.motscaches V/uppp﹕ down
05-09 15:03:26.885  24856-24856/fr.myApp.motscaches V/uppp﹕ up
```

My class : public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{ ...

```
    activy = act;
    mainThread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);
    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.v("uppp","down");
                    terr.touch2(event.getX(),event.getY());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.v("uppp","up");
                    terr.raz();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    terr.touch(event.getX(),event.getY());
                    break;

            }
            return  true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please fix your question, it is unclear what you are asking. Also properly format the code.

Comment: redrawing the view has nothing to do with it (I've tried it myself) but what exactly is your problem? that the "up" inside the log is fired while your finger is still on the screen? It could also be the device's fault have you tried a different device?

Comment: yes I have the "up" while my finger is still on the screen. I'm going to try with a new device.

Comment: What were your results after trying on a different device? Do you still have this question?